# SSIS Compare Unicode Text fields conditional split

Tags: ssis, compare, conditional-operator

Hi i have an ssis package where i need to compare two Unicode Text fields (Long Text) but not sure how i can do this. Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Thanks

i tried a simple compare but it fails. Below is similar to what I am trying in my conditional split

Text1 != Text2 ? True:False

Comment: What you are doing is the correct method to compare text. Seems like you might have a different issue and without examples it is difficult to ascertain. Also, Text1 != Text2 yields the same result. No need to clarify the true/false part.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Both columns are DT_NTEXT and are outputted from a KingswaySoft source component. lookmlike comparing  DT_NTEXT columns dont like the above method.

Comment: NTEXT is actually a varbinary data type (stream is another way to call it) and not a string. Are these columns really that big? If they are not really that big, I suggest either reading them as strings or convert them to strings before comparison. If the data is really big enough to use a stream, then maybe comparing them is not the best solution.

Comment: When I say maybe not the best solution, I mean use another field. For example, I am guessing here, but if you are looking to see if there is a change in that field, instead of comparing big strings, check if the update date is newer than what is currently recorded.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the compared texts are shorter that 4000 characters you can write the condition:

```
(DT_WSTR, 4000) Text1 !=  (DT_WSTR, 4000) Text2
```

That would be the most effective solution.

But, if you wanted to compare longer texts with DT_NTEXT data type and, as the DT_NTEXT is actually a binary format, you can use the below solution.

I wrote the whole example.

I created a database with one table and two columns to compare:

```
CREATE DATABASE TextDatabase;
GO

USE TextDatabase;
GO

CREATE TABLE Texts(Text1 NTEXT, Text2 NTEXT);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Texts(Text1, Text2) VALUES ('TEXT TO COMPARE', 'TEXT TO COMPARE');
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Texts(Text1, Text2) VALUES ('TEXT TO COMPARE2', 'text to compare two');
GO
```

Then I created a data flow in SSIS:

[image]

Then in Show Advanced Editor option:

[image]

I changed data type to DT_IMAGE (as it is the blob data type in SSIS).

[image]

I configured the Script Component as a transformation to compare hashes of byte arrays:

[image]

[image]

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
```

```
    private bool AreHashesEqual(byte[] inputBytes1, byte[] inputBytes2)
    {
        using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create())
        {
            byte[] hashBytes1 = sha256.ComputeHash(inputBytes1);
            byte[] hashBytes2 = sha256.ComputeHash(inputBytes2);

            return hashBytes1.SequenceEqual(hashBytes2);
        }
    }

    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
    {
        byte[] inputBytes1 = Row.Text1.GetBlobData(0, (int)Row.Text1.Length);
        byte[] inputBytes2 = Row.Text2.GetBlobData(0, (int)Row.Text2.Length);

        Row.ComparisonResult = AreHashesEqual(inputBytes1, inputBytes2);
    }
```

In the vier the is the correct result:

[image]

Note: The above solution compares byte arrays, so it doesn't consider letter case and doesn't trim spaces.